# Plotting graph (tikz, pgf) from .csv. Error: Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

I'm getting following error trying to plot .csv table (*link to the table:* https://github.com/JKhay/LaTeX) to an article:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \penalty 
l.107 ...emicolon, each nth point=10] {C1PDF.csv};
                                                  ^^M

        Missing \endcsname inserted.
    <to be read again> 
                       \penalty 
    l.107 ...emicolon, each nth point=10] {C1PDF.csv};
                                                      ^^M

    Package pgfplots Warning: Table 'C1PDF.csv' has non-unique column name '\penalty \@M e'. 
Only the first occurence can be accessed via column names. on input line 107.
```

the code for the tikz picture:

```
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width=70 mm,
    height=70 mm,
    y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.1,.5)},rotate=0,anchor=south},
    xlabel={Displacement [nm]},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd },
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,,1000 sep={\,}, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=0, /tikz/.cd}, scaled ticks=false,
    ylabel={Load [mN]},
    xmin=0, xmax=350,
    ymin=0, ymax=2.7,
    xtick={0,100,200,300},
    ytick={0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    legend columns=2,
    legend style={at={(0.19,0.98)},anchor=north west},
    legend entries={Clinker, CH , Inner p., Outer p.},
    ]

    \addplot [color=magenta, thick] table [x=dC, y=LC, col sep=semicolon, each nth point=10] {C1PDF.csv};
    \addplot [color=green, thick] table [x=dCH, y=LCH, col sep=semicolon, each nth point=10] {C1PDF.csv};
    \addplot [color=cyan, thick] table [x=dIP, y=LIP, col sep=semicolon, each nth point=10] {C1PDF.csv};
    \addplot [color=red, thick] table [x=dS, y=LS, col sep=semicolon, each nth point=10] {C1PDF.csv};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Typical load-displacement curves.}
    \label{fig:curves}
\end{figure}
```

The line 107 refers to:

```
\addplot [color=magenta, thick] table [x=dC, y=LC, col sep=semicolon, each nth point=10] {C1PDF.csv};
```

The header and footer of the article:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
.
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

So, there shouldn't be any package missing. Also, the .csv file is in the same directory as main .tex file that I compile.

Do you have any suggestions, please?

Thank You.

Comment: I downloaded your file and find that at the very first position of the data file there is a non-ASCII character. After removing this non-ASCII character, your file runs through on my up-to-date TeXLive 2019 installation.

Comment: I haven't noticed that at all and I have tried many things... Do you mean the "e" character in A1 cell? Did you remove it or convert it ASCII (in this case, can you, please, give me a hint how did you modify the cell?)

Comment: There was/is an invisible character before the `e`, which I removed. Then it worked.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I tried to find the non-ASCII character you mentioned - without luck (see not an 'answer'). Nevertheless, (evil) invisibel characters from copy-and-paste often caused me trouble in the past :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner In my editor the character looks like this: `ï»¿`. I still can run the code after removing this. Can you perhaps try to use https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/ to remove these characters?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if I understand you correctly. I tried pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover  and do not see anything suspicious :) (see updated "answer"). Anyway, it#s not about me, it's about the OP. If this solves the problem - good. I was just curious why I do not see the problematic characters :).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the comment. However, as _Dr. Manuel Kuehner_ mentioned, I also don't see the non-ASCII character and I'm focusing only on the `"e"`. Did you use mentioned [https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/] to detect it? Or can you, please, upload a corrected `.csv` file, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Just delete the first line completely and replace it by `e;PDF;ec6;pdfc6;dC;LC;dS;LS;dCH;LCH;dIP;LIP`. And maybe use https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/. The csv file is too long to be uploaded, I am afraid.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat It worked, thanks! One more thing. I'm plotting another graph and getting following error: `Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'srp.98' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'srp.98'..`. This repeats for `z·∞.98`, `lis.98`, `pro.98`, `˙no.53`, `b∞e.53`, `kv•.53`, `£vn.53`. I have tried to rewrite it, then removed the diacritics using (pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/) but it doesn't work. Can you, please, look at this one last thing for me, whether these cells are properly formatted? Thanks

Comment: I think you simply cannot use any of the `∞` and so on characters, I am afraid. There is nothing I can do about that. AFAIK you can only use ASCII characters in plot files.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I though as much, so I've I removed the diacritics "á", "č", "ě", "ř", "ú",... but I'm still getting the same error. Strangly, after removing these char for non-diacritics, the error hasn't change a bit, pointing that there a still characters such as `∞` , etc. Also in case od "lis.98" or "pro.98", everything should be fine in my opinion without any need for editing.

Comment: I think you cannot have periods in column  names either. It is hard for me to debug this because I do not have an explicit example.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I see. Here is the link for the graph if you find some time to look at it: [https://github.com/JKhay/LaTeX/blob/master/Graph] , thanks. However, I think that you're right, the periods are still causing me problems.

Answer (score 2):

*Not an answer!*

- I tried to see about the comment of user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703.
- Here's a screenshot of the file (from https://github.com/JKhay/LaTeX, see question).
- I cannot see a 'strange' character in front of the first line.
- Maybe user https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703 can clarify his findings.

[image]

[image]